# Note QGIS raster calculator defaults to not being accurate

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, population

[Edited title of post based on fact that @wingnut solved it]

I'm trying to normalise a population density map such as [this one](https://data.worldpop.org/GIS/Population/Global_2000_2020_1km/2020/GBR/gbr_ppp_2020_1km_Aggregated.tif) (e.g. to a maximum of 255). The maximum value in the file to begin with is 27500.1. However, if I enter `("gbr_pd_2020_1km@1" * 255) / 27500.1` as a formula in the Raster Calculator it only gives me values up to 198.

What makes me further think it's a bug is if I just enter as a formula `"gbr_pd_2020_1km@1" / 27500.1`, it should give me values up to 1, but it only gives me values up to 0.8. And even if I just enter `itself * 1` it only gives me values up to 21367!!! Please see

[image: attached screenshot.]

What I think must be happening is that the 27500.1 value is only in one pixel (which represents one area in London) and somehow the raster calculator is not looking at every pixel. But I can't see any settings to change this.

I've also tried doing the same via 'Processing Toolbox' then GDAL Raster Calculator, but it gives the same incorrect results.

I've tried this in QGIS 3.16.5 and 3.18 (the latest LTR and beta releases available), and am running it on the latest version of Mac OS (Big Sur 11.2.3).

Comment: I get a maximum for the input of 14687.8. Where did you get 27500.1? That's the max of the colorbar, not the data. Go to the Layer Styling panel and make sure you have selected the actual min and max, rather than a cumulative count, mean/stdev etc. See if it changes to 1468.7.

Comment: @wingnut Thanks very much. Sorry I linked the wrong file. I meant the one below. However with the one I originally linked to, I have exactly the same problem if I divide by 14687.8 (or times by 1 etc.). https://data.worldpop.org/GIS/Population_Density/Global_2000_2020_1km/2020/GBR/gbr_pd_2020_1km.tif

Comment: Actually, it is working, but looks like it isn't. You need to change one thing. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to happen by default. The maximum you see is an estimate based on sampling. You want the actual maximum of all samples in the raster.

In the **Layer Styling** panel, under *Accuracy*, select *Actual(slower)*. The legend should then display 255 as required.

**Raster Calculator**
[image: Setup]

This produces the bad range, like this:

[image]

But if you look at the **Layer Styling** Panel, you see:

[image]

which looks wrong. Notice, however, that the **Accuracy** is set to *Estimate(faster)*. Changing this to *Actual(slower)*, 2 things happen. Firstly, the maximum in the Layer Styling panel changes to 255 as required:

[image]

Secondly, the legend updates to the new value:

[image]

Comment: well spotted, it is a bit strange that Estimate method is choosen by default. I understand it as consequences on rendering but at least, a warning should be displayed.

Comment: Thanks very much wingnut and simo. Just to emphasise for others who are having this problem - it's the styling on the layer which you create that matters; not the original layer. I agree that it's strange that it doesn't default to 'correct' or flag a warning, or say anything in the tool or the manual on this. I appreciate you could say 'it's open source - you fix it' but I wouldn't know where to start (and would rather support others who like doing that). Anyway, thanks very much again!

Comment: FYI, I have created a new feature request : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/42847

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with raster format manipulation with QGIS but indeed, it sounds strange.

Anyway, you can get the wanted result by using grass `r.rescale` command (using Processing Tools) :

> The r.rescale program rescales the range of category values appearing
> in a raster map layer. A new raster map layer, and an appropriate
> category file and color table based upon the original raster map
> layer, are generated with category labels that reflect the original
> category values that produced each category. This command is useful
> for producing representations with a reduced number of categories from
> a raster map layer with a large range of category values (e.g.,
> elevation).

[image: r.rescale]

If you want to know more on `r.rescale` option, have a look on the documentation : https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/r.rescale.html

And maybe notify the possible bug to the QGIS community : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Ok thanks. I can't immediately get it to work (fails to give an output) but I'll read the documentation properly and try again. Many thanks for the response. Would you recommend another programme for raster manipulation e.g. arcgis?

Comment: I love GRASS GIS because it is powerful and reliable ! I had no problem to rescale the raster you mentioned and linked in your first post, only by setting options as in screenshot.

Comment: It will have the same problem (he was displaying the estimated maximum, not the actual maximum) in the QGIS Layer Styling panel.

Comment: @wingnut : no, it displays 0 to 255 values, because by default when new raster layer is created it is displayed as 'Palette / unique value". But you're right, same rendering option apply when switching to "pseudo color ..." render.